# Microsoft Graph List Contacts API returns contacts beyond what are visible in the Outlook UI

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

### Outlook UI

You can see that I've made [three test contacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJMEn.png) in the UI accessible here: https://outlook.live.com/people/

### Microsoft Graph List Contacts API

When I call the [List Contacts API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-contacts?view=graph-rest-beta) (`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts?$orderby=createdDateTime desc&$top=50`), I get a list of contacts that is much more extensive than the list visible in the UI. These contacts appear to be anyone that has emailed me or anyone that I've emailed.

### The problem

If I want to poll against the `GET /me/contacts` endpoint to get some data whenever I make a new contact, I'll end up getting notified every time someone new sends me an email or every time I send someone new an email (even if I didn't manually create the contact).

Is this intentional? If so, are there any filters I could add to specify that I don't want to get contacts that were not manually created by me? Looking over the [JSON representation of a contact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/contact?view=graph-rest-beta#json-representation), I don't see anything I can filter on.

### Possible Solution

My only thought is that I notice that the contacts made for me exist in a folder that is not returned in the [contactFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-contactfolders?view=graph-rest-beta) API endpoint. I could theoretically make a call to that endpoint and take the list of contacts returned and check if the `parentFolderId` exists in there. If it does, presumably that's because we created a contact and if not then it's made for us. That feels terribly hacky, though.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the Microsoft Graph Beta APIs. Switching to the v1.0 of the Graph REST APIs resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Outlook automatically adds every email address that had been in contact with the user as a hidden contact in a hidden folder.

The `GET beta/me/contacts` endpoint (unlike the `v1.0` one) returns all contacts from all folders, so it also includes this hidden folder.

There are two ways to get the expected list of contacts:

**Option 1** - get all contacts, and then filter:

1. `GET /beta/me/contactFolders` to obtain a list of "real" folders (this endpoint does not return that hidden folder)
2. `GET /beta/me/contacts` to get all contacts in the account
3. Filter the list of contacts by field `parentFolderId` - to keep only contacts in one of the folders returned at step 1

**Option 2** - get contacts by folder:

1. `GET /beta/me/contactFolders` to obtain a list of "real" folders (this endpoint does not return that hidden folder)
2. for each folder returned call `GET /beta/me/contactFolders/{folder-id}/contacts` and aggregate the returned contact lists

Hope this helps.